# Key Mapping do SmartCSV não muda as chaves do Hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, hash

Tenho um arquivo CSV que faço a interpretação por meio do SmartCSV. Porém, preciso que os nomes das chaves dos hashes gerados sejam alterados, para uso estou usando o key_mapping do SmartCSV mas ele não está alterando os nomes.

Uma parte do arquivo CSV original:

```
ID da Organização;Nome da Organização;último acesso
81;company_81;2000-01-01 00:00:00
```

Este é a parte que é feita a interpretação:

```
file = File.open(org_file.path)
options = {
  col_sep: ';',
  header_transformations: [ key_mapping: {:id_da_organização => :id, :nome_da_organização => :name, :último_acesso => :last_access} ]
}
@file = SmarterCSV.process(file.path, options)
```

Os hashes do @file após essa parte ficam assim:

```
:id_da_organização=>81, :nome_da_organização=>"company_81", :último_acesso=>"2000-01-01 00:00:00"
```

Mas eu queria que as chaves mudassem de acordo com o que eu pedi.

Answer (score -1):

Ajudou a documentação obtida no seguinte link: https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/smarter_csv/1.2.6

Não encontrei File_open.

Funcionou o seguinte código:

^
require 'smarter_csv'

file_path = 'csv.csv'
options = {
col_sep: ';',
header_transformations:
[ key_mapping: {:id_da_organização => :id,
:nome_da_organização => :name, :último_acesso => :last_access } ]
}

file = SmarterCSV.process('csv.csv', options)
puts file
^

Resposta impressa:
➜  CSVSmart ruby csv.rb
{:id_da_organização=>81, :nome_da_organização=>"company_81", :último_acesso=>"2000-01-01 00:00:00"}